# How to make the recharts barchart full width responsively

Tags: responsive, recharts

My recharts' bar chart won't extend when I change the width of the website.
How can I make my chart's width stretch to full?
I tried deleting width and height, then it just disappears. I also tried having min-width or height in the ResponsiveContainer, that doesn't work. Please help me.

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <div>
            <BarChart
              className='m-auto'
              data={data}
              margin={{
                top: 20,
                right: 30,
                left: 30,
                bottom: 5,
              }}
              width={900}
              height={400}
              >
              <XAxis
                dataKey, etc,.
              />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the responsive container with a `<div></div>`. Apply width or height to that `<div></div>`.

```
<div style={{ height: "20rem" }}>
  <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
    >
      <XAxis dataKey="name"></XAxis>

      <YAxis tick={(tickObject) => customTick(tickObject)}></YAxis>

      <Line dataKey="uv" type="monotone" stroke="#0000FF"></Line>
      <Line dataKey="pv" type="monotone" stroke="#ff223f"></Line>

      {/* Tooltip Implementation */}
      <Tooltip
        content={<CustomTooltip active={false} payload={[]} label={""} />}
      />

      {/* Legend Implementation */}
      <Legend content={<RenderLegend />} verticalAlign="top" />
    </LineChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
</div>
```

This solution worked for me you can find code snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-bar-chart-5j31b0?file=/src/Components/CustomTooltipAndLegendComponent.jsx)

Comment: This still doesn't work tho